# Python - Use %s in value of config file

Tags: sql, python-3.x, ini

I use a config file (**type .ini**) to save my SQL queries, then i get  a query by its key. All work fine, until creating a query with parameters, example :

```
;the ini file

product_by_cat = select * from products where cat =%s
```

I use :

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
args= ('cat1')
config.read(path_to_ini_file)
query= config.get(section_where_are_stored_thequeries,key_of_the_query)
complete_query= query%args
```

I get the error :

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

So it try to format the string at retrieving the value from the ini file.
Any proposition of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `format` function like this

ini file

```
  product_by_cat = select * from products where cat ={}
```

python:

```
 complete_query= query.format(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on the versions of `ConfigParser` (Python 2 or Python 3) you may need to double the `%` like this or it throws an error:

```
product_by_cat = select * from products where cat =%%s
```

Although a better way would be to use the raw version of the config parser, so the `%` char isn't interpreted

```
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
```